# Load all field collections of a given type

Tags: entities

Currently I am using a query to load field collections of a specified type, but I wonder if there is a more drupaly way to do it?

```
$query = db_select('field_collection_item', 'fci')
  ->fields('fci', array('field_name', 'item_id'))
  ->condition('fci.field_name', $field_collection_name)
;

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('item_id');
$fcs = entity_load('field_collection_item', array_keys($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have field collection with type 'field_my_dates'. So you can get field collection details using node and collection type as given below.

```
<?PHP
    $itemCollection = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_dates');
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this would load field collections of only a single node? That's not what I want -- I want to get all field collections of a particular type.